# Using output Feature Dataset of Import XML Workspace process as parameter for continued processing in same model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-dataset

I am setting up a model for some automated SDE creation.  As of now, I manually import XML Workspace schema to a new SDE database, then run a model where I manually input the created Feature Dataset from the XML import.  I would like to incorporate the Import XML Workspace tool into my model.

How do I "grab" that created Feature Dataset and use it as a variable for the rest of my model processes?